# Error when building Tensorflow 1.0 - Jpeg

Tags: tensorflow

Platform - Linux
LibJpegTurbo 1.5.1

In file included from external/jpeg/jpeglib.h:31:0,
                 from external/jpeg/jccolor.c:18:
external/jpeg/jmorecfg.h:209:33: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'static'
 #define LOCAL(type)             static type

external/jpeg/jdcolext.c:30:1: note: in expansion of macro 'LOCAL'

Note - i amended the build file and it is possible i broke something. From the looks of it, it is able to find locate the files but there is an error with LOCAL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved - there was an invisible character in the file